# My server is set to port 3000, but when I run it the terminal says "Local: http://localhost:4001"

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I'm working with react and the port is set to 3000 in my code, I've checked everywhere to make sure and have even changed the port number, but no matter what when I run my program it says localhost:4001, but my program is running fine and displaying all the content and I'm not getting any errors. Is there something I'm missing here? Why would this be happening?

I tried doing lsof to see if something is running on any of these ports, but I get an error there saying zsh: command not found: lsof, so that's another separate issue which i checked my path, tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but nothing works. I've done killall and tried running it again but it's still 4001 when I run it, but my code says 3000.

Comment: In the Package.json, Rewrite script this way: "start": "PORT=3000 react-scripts start" and it will run on 3000.

Comment: Please post your code and your package.json.